# Pagination for lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if anyone knows if any great plugins for pagination on unordered and ordered lists, I would like an easy but highly customisable plugin. If anyone has any suggestions that would be great, I've found this link below, has anyone used any before?

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

Comment: Can you show us what you already have?

Comment: What are you trying to paginate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your pick!

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/

Comment: Ha ha, I was just posting that same link :)

Comment: Just fastest finger first! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Int Icount = ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count(Total no of records, this should be come from Database tables);
        int startindexx = SIndex(here SIndex like a no of pages like 1,2,3,etc, it from your clicking pagination buttons);
        int EndIndex = SIndex;
        if (EndIndex == 1) { EndIndex = 0; }
        if (startindexx > 1) {
            startindexx = startindexx - 1;
            startindexx = startindexx * 10;
            startindexx = startindexx + 1;
            EndIndex = EndIndex * 10;
        }
        else {
            EndIndex = EndIndex + 10;
        }
        var Pages = 0; Pages = Icount / 10; var PagesReminder = Icount % 10;
        Icount = ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        int startindexx = Convert.ToInt32(SIndex);
        int EndIndex = Convert.ToInt32(SIndex);
        if (EndIndex == 1) {
            EndIndex = 0;
        }
        if (startindexx > 1) {
           startindexx = startindexx - 1;
           startindexx = startindexx * 10;
           startindexx = startindexx + 1;
           EndIndex = EndIndex * 10;
        }
        else {
           EndIndex = EndIndex + 10;
        }
        var Pages = 0; Pages = Icount / 10;
        var PagesReminder = Icount % 10;
        if (PagesReminder != 0) {
           Pages = Pages + 1; 
        }
```